# Does List<string> have a Changed event in c#?

Tags: c#

I have recently bought a book called "The c# programming language" 4th edition. On page 49 there is a reference to a List having a changed event that can be bound to as an example of events.
Have tried to reproduce this but ended up doing some head scratching with this :-

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Changed+= new EventHandler(ListChanged);
```

and so it continues....
Am I missing something or does List not have a changed event?

Comment: Note that the ObservableCollection<T> fires events if items are added or removed from the list, but not if one of the strings changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it does. However, the `List<T>` with a `Changed` event referenced on page 49 is actually introduced on page 40. It is *not* the `List<T>` that is part of the base class library. To use the version included in the book you will have to type it in yourself (or maybe the book comes with a CD, or perhaps you can download it), and your code will not be compatible any other code that uses the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` that everybody else uses.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh now I get it. Penny dropped Gabe. Thanks for that. Knew it would be down to me and my missing something :) Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

No, `List<T>` doesn't have such event, you are not missing anything. You may checkout the [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which has a [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event you could subscribe to. It is extensively used in WPF and Silverlight to implement the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Yeah am aware of observablecollection having that event. Just found myself wondering if was me when in a book by the guy who wrote the language it has that code sample.

Comment: and so it was me as Gabe rightly pointed out. It was referencing a class defined earlier on a different page. :S

Answer (score 5):

Nope, take a look at [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms668604.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event on `List<T>`. Maybe the book is refering to [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms668604.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObservableCollection and you can add the namespace for using those

```
Namespace: System.Collections.ObjectModel
Assembly: WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)
```